# Understanding a solution for implementing square() without using the multiplication operator

Tags: c++

I am currently working through Bjarne Stroustrup's *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++*. One of the "try this" exercises is to implement a square function without using the multiplication operator. A solution I found is:

```
int archaic_square(int v) {
  int total = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i) {
      total += v;
  }

return total;

}

int main() {

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      cout << i << '\t' << archaic_square(i) << '\n';
  }

}
```

I know this works and outputs the square of integers from 0 to 99 but I don't understand how it works. Could someone explain what exactly the function output as well as what the variable `total` would be as `v` increments?

I tried doing it on paper and working it out. Given that `v` is incrementing by 1 how does an input of `v = 2` into the function return 4? I seem to be getting 3 whenever I work it out by hand.

I'm sure this is a pretty straightforward problem, I'm just starting out and trying to understand this language.

Comment: How do you get the result 3 when working out `archaic_square(2)` on paper? Is it because you think *"given that v is incrementing by 1"*? No, `i` is incrementing by 1. `v` doesn't change.

Comment: `archaic_square()`  sets `total` to zero, then adds `v` to `total` exactly `v` times.

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. A debugger allows you to run the program at a rate you control so  you can keep up with and watch everything the program does as sit does it. As you can tell from the name, it's great for debugging, but it's also invaluable in figuring out the logic of non-bugged code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple you can think of multiplication as:
for example I say `3 * 5` it equivalent to I say `5 + 5 + 5` or `3 + 3 + 3 + 3 +3`.

The same way this function is summing `N` number `N` times. For example let say I pass `v=5`.
It will work like this:
`total= 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 25`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in doubt, I would suggest you print out the value for each iteration inside the function,

```
int archaic_square(int v) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i) {
        total += v;
        std::cout << "total= " << total << " where i= " << i << " \n"; // --- HERE ----
}

return total;
```

}

you should see output as

```
2  where i= 0
4  where i= 1
```

(when v is passed in as 2)

Answer (score 1):

At function `archaic_square` I start from 0 and this for loop repeat `v` time and each time total become `total` plus `v` and it is like `v * v`:

```cpp
int archaic_square(int v) {
    int total = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        total += v;
    }
    
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The square of a number is the same as adding that number the same number of times as that number. That's `archaic_square(int v)` and the purpose of `total` is, well, to be the total of adding `v` to itself `v` times. `v` is not being incremented by 1 in this function, `i` is.

In `main` this function is called with `i` going from 0, adding 1 to itself each loop, and continuing while `i` is less than 100. It is not less than 100 when it is 100, therefore it stops at 99.

It is important to note that the `i` in `archaic_square` is *not* the same `i` in main - that is the scope of the variable. They don't know of each other. It is important to note that is where `int i` is important. If you used just `i` then it *would* expect to have an `i` defined elsewhere outside that scope - you would get an error if you did that here and if you did that and then defined `i` globally they would interfere with each other and the whole thing would break.

`i` is commonly used as a loop variable name (**i**teration). so you will see this *a lot*.

Hence: squares from 0 to 99 are printed on the console.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, this is what I understood of this solution after going through a lot of head scratching myself, and I feel my comment in this function code is a pretty good explanation for total beginners!

```
int archaic_square(int v) 

{

int total =0;

for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i) //this loop will repeat v times (until i is less than v; keep increasing i)
{
    total += v; 

    /*Let us take the example of v = 5. So variable 'i' (which is in the for loop) will keep incrementing by 1 if value is less than 5.
    So loop will repeat 5 times. So each time loop repeats the new value of total will become  
    total = (total +5). This process will repeat 5 times. As value of the variable total is zero, the final value of total will be: 
    (total + 5) + (total + 5) + (total + 5) + (total + 5) + (total + 5).
    [Since total value is 0, 5 is getting added 5 times, which is 25 which is 5 times 5] 
    Hence, this loop is doing multiplication.*/
}

return total;
}
```

Happy Coding!